# by using drush7 how to install a contributed module

Tags: php, drupal-7, drush

But my teriminal is showing the error below... what is the solution for this...

```
[error] Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will
need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
The drush command 'en ckeditor' could not be executed.
```

Comment: Make sure you are in the directory of your drupal installation, it is what cause this error usually (your drush install did not define a root directory for drupal in env variables, wich is usefull if you have multiple drupal sites on the same server).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on a drupal directory. So if your drupal site sits at `/var/www/html/mysite` then you need to be in the `mysite` directory and run commands. 
To download a module `drush pm-download <modulename>` 
To enable a module `drush pm-enable <module_name>`. 
To disable a module `drush pm-disable <module_name>`.

Answer (score -1):

Per the official documentation, **Drush - Installing a module with Drush**, (found at: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/extending-drupal-7/installing-contributed-modules#adv)

The commands are `drush dl module_name` and `drush en module_name`.

Comment: `drush en` is [just an alias for `drush pm-enable`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/pm/pm-enable/). OP is likely to get the same error there.